# Set current date to jDateChooser

Tags: mysql, netbeans, jdatechooser, jcalendar

I'm working on a project in netbeans and MySQL Workbech.
I have a Signup form and I want the user to pick a date. If they don't pick a date I want to use today's date as default.

I'm using jcalendar 1.4. 
How can I set today's date as a default?

I've already used

```
jDateChooser1.setDateFormatString("yyyy-mm-dd ");
```

so that my date would be compatible with MySQL DATE format.

Answer (score 1):

To set today's date with format :

```
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();  
 String currDateString = dateFormat.format(now);
 JdateChooser.setDate(now);
```

you can also do this :

```
   java.util.Date date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(currDateString );
```

**update:**  based your comment it will work :

```
jDateChooser1.setDate(java.sql.Date.valueOf(java.time.LocalDate.now())); 
pst.setString(5,((JTextField)jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
```

Comment: I've got an error: **LocalDateTime cannot be converted to String**

Comment: No. I used: `jDateChooser1.setDate(java.sql.Date.valueOf(java.time.LocalDate.now()));
            pst.setString(5,((JTextField)jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());`